# local.testsettings file that is sensitive to configuration

Tags: mstest

I am building a library that is built in an x86 and x64 configuration.  In unit testing I have to have two files that I select manually one has deployment items from the x64 direcotry and the other has deployment items from the x86 directory. I also have to modify the  tag with the attribute hostProcessPlatform="MSIL" for the x64 COM components to run and load correctly.  My question is how do I write the deployment items and Execution items in the file such that dependent upon the current configuration setting it does the right thing

I would like to do something like this

```
<DeploymentItem filename = "$(Config)\file">
...
...
about 50  different deployment items then 

<Execution Configuration="x86" >
...
</Execution>
<Execution Configuration="x64">
...
</Execution>
```

any one out there ever run into this and figured it out?

Comment: Have fugured out how to use environment settings to modify the deployment paths but still need to know how to conditionally set hostProcessPlatform to either "x86" or "MSIL" depending on whether I am building an x86 or a x64 output configuration. This tag does not support the Condition attribute.